# Control visibility of layout Block on the basis of session value

Tags: magento2, layout

I want to display a layout block only when there is some attribute is set in customer session.
It can be controlled with a config value. Is it possible to do it with session too?

Answer (score 0):

You can do but you'll have issues with Caches. Better to utilize something live Magento 2 private content in your case.

Refference:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html

Examples:

- https://belvg.com/blog/customer-data-management-in-magento-2.html
- https://amasty.com/blog/how-to-use-sections-in-magento-2/